# Dynamic pricing table/feature matrix with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am working on building out a pricing table/feature matrix (picture of what I am trying to build below)

[image]

I have the base built out, but I am running into trouble with the price rollups at the bottom, specifically for the 'Entrepreneur' and 'Business Pro' columns.

I want to be able to add new rows (new features) onto this and have the bottom prices adjust (move downwards) accordingly. Right now I am using relative positioning, which isn't going to work since I would need to adjust it every time a new feature/row is added.

Codepen Link: http://codepen.io/er40/pen/NxeZpq

```css
.box {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
/* Services Col */

.services-table {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 114px;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.services-table tr {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
}
.services-table tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.services-table th.services {
  color: #707478;
  font-weight: 100;
  min-width: 375px;
  background: #fff;
}
/* Entrepreneur and Business Pro Col */

table.price-matrix {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  float: left;
}
table.price-matrix tr {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
}
/* Headers */

table.price-matrix th.header-white {
  color: #707478;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #fff;
}
table.price-matrix th.header-white:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
th.header-white hr,
th.header-green hr {
  width: 70%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
/* Rows */

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #f7fafb;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td.td-green {
  background: #489a5a;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td.td-green {
  background: #54aa66;
}
td.border {
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
/* Enterprise */

.enterprise {
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .21);
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .21);
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.enterprise tr {
  height: 40px;
}
th.header-green {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 0 15px;
  background: #54aa66;
}
.enterprise tr.price {
  height: 100px;
}
.enterprise tr.price-border {
  height: 10px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  left: 380px;
  bottom: 110px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section id="pakete">
  <div class="box">
    <!-- The surrounding box -->

    <!-- The front container -->
    <div class="front">
      <table class="services-table">
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="price-matrix" border="0">
        <tr>
          <th class="header-white">Entrepreneur
            <hr />
          </th>
          <th class="header-white">Business Pro
            <hr />
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="enterprise">
        <th class="header-green">Enterprise
          <hr />
        </th>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="price">
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="price-border">
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <span>19</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't know if this question is generic enough to be suited for the Stack Overflow forum. I would suggest you try to make the question more generic.

Comment: @Gewthen - Why does a question have to be "generic"?

Comment: You have to think about how this question will be useful for others. What is the crux of your problem? The pricing matrix aspect has nothing to do with the technical aspect of the problem, but you are presenting it as such. So I would clean up the question to reflect the technical problem you are having. It looks like you are having trouble aligning several tables together such that they look as one. Have you thought about making one entire table?

Comment: @Gewthen - yes I started out making it all as one table. The challenge is handling the drop shadows. If you look at the image I posted above, you will see the first 2 plan's columns have a dropshadow, and then the far right plan's column is a different drop shadow that extends over the others. Also, the far right's column needs to be taller than the others, so it made sense to have them as seperate tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many more solutions for this UI, but according to me, this is the quickest/standardised way to achieve this. This layout is also responsive as well.

Note: I have used many [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) [Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to avoid [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

```js
function priceTable() {
  var whiteLeft = $('.white-left').innerWidth(),
    greenWidth = $('.green-width').innerWidth(),
    whiteHeight = $('.price').innerHeight();

  $('.bg-white').css({
    'left': whiteLeft,
    'bottom': whiteHeight
  });

  $('.bg-green').css({
    'width': greenWidth
  });
};

$(document).ready(priceTable);
$(window).on('resize load', priceTable);
```

```css
body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font: 13px/16px sans-serif;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
}
.main .bg-white,
.main .bg-green {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.main .bg-white {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  top: 20px;
}
.main .bg-green {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.price-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
.price-table .min {
  height: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.price-table tr:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}
.price-table tr:nth-child(2n) td:not(:first-child,
:last-child,
.price) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.price-table tr:nth-child(2n) td:last-child {
  background: #428c52;
}
.price-table tr td {
  padding: 20px;
}
.price-table tr td:not(:first-child) {
  text-align: center;
}
.price-table tr td:last-child {
  background: #489a5a;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <span class="bg-white"></span>
  <span class="bg-green"></span>
  <table class="price-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="min" colspan="3"></td>
        <td class="min"></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="white-left">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Entrepreneur</td>
        <td>Business Pro</td>
        <td class="green-width">Enterprise</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Service 1</td>
        <td>yes</td>
        <td>yes</td>
        <td>yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Service 2</td>
        <td>yes</td>
        <td>yes</td>
        <td>yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Service 3</td>
        <td>yes</td>
        <td>yes</td>
        <td>yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Service 4</td>
        <td>yes</td>
        <td>yes</td>
        <td>yes</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="price">$19/month</td>
        <td class="price">$19/month</td>
        <td>$19/month</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great!! Absolutely perfect. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Okay, this isn't exactly like the image. But I think it will be the most efficient for actually adding data. If you didn't need to add additional data(at least to my knowledge and experience), you could make it look exactly like the image above. The way box shadow works though, I was personally unable to make it function exactly.

Remove the `<span>` and change the span class to `.price`. Remove the `Display: inline-block;` as well. I also added `.td-white`, which will give the white pricing the look you are wanting(minus the drop shadow). I think this is what you're looking for:

UPDATED*Reference: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMZBqG

HTML:

```
<section id="pakete">
  <div class="box">
    <!-- The surrounding box -->

    <!-- The front container -->
    <div class="front">
      <table class="services-table">
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="services">Service 1</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="price-matrix" border="0">
        <tr>
          <th class="header-white">Entrepreneur
            <hr />
          </th>
          <th class="header-white">Business Pro
            <hr />
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td class="entypo-cancel"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="price">
          <td class="td-white">20</td>
          <td class="td-white">20</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="enterprise">
        <th class="header-green">Enterprise
          <hr />
        </th>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="price">
          <td class="td-green">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="price-border">
          <td class="td-green"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}


/* Services Col */

.services-table {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 114px;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.services-table tr {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.services-table tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.services-table th.services {
  color: #707478;
  font-weight: 100;
  min-width: 375px;
  background: #fff;
}


/* Entrepreneur and Business Pro Col */

table.price-matrix {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  float: left;
}

table.price-matrix tr {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
}


/* Headers */

table.price-matrix th.header-white {
  color: #707478;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #fff;
}

table.price-matrix th.header-white:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

th.header-white hr,
th.header-green hr {
  width: 70%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}


/* Rows */

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #f7fafb;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td.td-green {
  background: #489a5a;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td.td-green {
  background: #54aa66;
}

td.border {
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}


/* Enterprise */

.enterprise {
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .21);
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .21);
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.enterprise tr {
  height: 40px;
}

th.header-green {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 0 15px;
  background: #54aa66;
}

.enterprise tr.price {
  height: 100px;
}

.enterprise tr.price-border {
  height: 10px;
}

.price {
  text-align:center;
  width:230px;
  position:relative;
  left:380px;
  bottom:110px;
  font-size:60px;
}

.td-white {
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}
```

This should allow you to add new services and have the bottom pricing move dynamically with it.

Comment: Not quite, take a look at the image I attached at the top. I don't want the prices for the first two plan's columns inside the actual table. They should be "floating" below their respective columns. I originally tried to do it the way you did, but with the drop shadows in the original design it didn't work.

Comment: Edit: Just saw your edit and that you are still working on it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check it out now. It's as close as I could get with as much functionality as possible. It's tough, at least in my knowledge and experience to make it work EXACT while keeping it functional to add and remove from the table.

Comment: Also, if you were already knowledgeable on this, than you may have came to this conclusion already. I don't think it's possible with the drop shadows and keeping the functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, much appreciated. I did come to the same conclusion, but was hoping I was missing something or that someone else had a better idea.

Comment: No worries! I realized after reading through everything you figured that out for yourself.